# Adding an extra page to an existing website with Chrome Extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I would like to create an extension that adds extra pages to and existing website. For example, I would like to add https://stackoverflow.com/statistics to stackoverflow so I can populate it with custom statistics.

**Can this be done?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You can either use redirection ([`chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html#event-onBeforeRequest)), or rewrite/add controls to the current page using [content scripts](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html). When you pick the latter option, the page must "exists" though. A 404 error page is OK, but a non-existent domain will fail (because Chrome will then display their own error page, and these cannot be scripted).

Comment: So, if I understand this correctly, after picking up the onBeforeRequest event, I'll change the page and throw in my own content?

Comment: Yes, `return {url: 'http://ownpage/'}`. It's a true redirection though, the user will see that the URL changes. In the past, I've tried to redirect to an extension page, but that was not reliable (in incognito mode, nothing showed up).